# Nmap Shows all ports are closed

Tags: nmap, metasploit, ports, metasploitable

I am facing a problem with Nmap while scanning metasploitable.

I am using two different PCs. One with Kali Linux by using USB boot and on other PC using Metasploitable running on VMWare. I have configured the IP address in both machines and they can ping each other because I have configured the VMWare in Bridge connection mode. All are working fine but when I use Nmap to scan my metasploitable then it shows that

"1 host is up but all 1000 ports are closed"

Actually the above is not the exact error but the meaning is exactly same.

Comment: What were you expecting to see? \

Comment: I expecting to see the list of all open ports.. because when I try to scan from my virtual machine's kali linux then it shows the open ports but from different PC it shows ports are closed.

Comment: What you described is different from the question. You might need to describe the networking between the 2 machines better. What machine is scanning? Can you ping from the scanning machine to the target? Explain like we are 5 years old.

Comment: I have two PCs . one is running on Kali Linux and the target machine is on windows 7. In the windows 7 machine I have VM installed and on that VM I am running Metasploitable. So the problem is that whenever I try to ping the Metasploitable i.e the target machine from my Kali linux machine then the ping works successfully but when I use nmap to scan for open ports then it doesn't show the open ports.

Comment: Right, then what you are pinging is not Metasploitable, but Windows 7. And Windows is likely blocking the scan with its firewall. This looks like a networking or a VMWare question and not a security question.

Comment: Lashing out  is not helpful.